# php converting float to int using type casting

Tags: php, floating-point, int, type-conversion

So I am reading the php manual on its types and am playing around with them. I have:

```
var_dump((int)0.8 + 0.2)
```

why does this return `0.2`?

I have no idea why.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It first evaluates `(int)0.8`, which is 0, then it adds 0.2. You need to use,

```
var_dump((int)(0.8 + 0.2))
```